Does Visual Studio slnx can fully replace old sln (Visual Studio Solution) format?
With .NET 9 (actually a bit earlier) and Visual Studio 2022 Microsoft have introduced a new Visual Studio Solution format .slnx also referred as Visual Studio Solution XML. As of December 2024 it is still in preview.
How does it compare to old .sln format.
Are there any drawbacks e.g. tools or features that still need existence of the .sln file in the solution directory?
I have started to use .slnx file in the existing solution after updating to .Net 9. The old file .sln is still present but I see that it is becoming more and more outdated as new projects are being added to the solution. Does it make sense to update it? Is it save to delete it?
UPDATE: My questions is related to current state of support for .slnx format. Is it fully supported in VS2022, what functions/tools work and which do not (This update is for someone who closed this question as opinion based. I am not interested in opinions.)
